# Multithreading with spacy: Is joblib necessary?

Tags: python, spacy

In [this](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#section-multithreading) part of the documentation, it is mentioned that `nlp.pipe()` works in parallel and the following example is given:

```
for doc in nlp.pipe(texts, batch_size=10000, n_threads=3):
    pass
```

After that, another, longer example is given that makes use of joblib. I don't quite understand the relationship between the two. As I understand the documentation, if I simply want to parallelize the tokenisation of many documents, the above, simple for loop will work and I do not have to use joblib, right?

My pipeline looks like this:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser', 'ner', 'textcat'])
```

When would I need to use joblib?

Comment: I can't see the Joblib example in the Doc., could you mention it?

Comment: Me neither, it has been removed with an update I guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on an answer in [Spacy github issues](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2075#issuecomment-449074687):

> We kept the n_threads argument to avoid breaking people's code, but
>   unfortunately the implementation doesn't currently release the GIL,
>   the way we did in v1. In v2 the neural network model is more
>   complicated and more subject to change, so we haven't implemented it
>   in Cython. We might at a later date.
>
> In v2.1.0 (you can get an alpha by installing spacy-nightly, the
>   matrix multiplications are now single-threaded. This makes it safe to
>   launch multiple processes for the pipeline, so we can look at doing
>   that internally. In the meantime, the n_threads argument sits
>   idle...Which I agree is confusing, but removing it and breaking
>   backwards compatibility seems worse.

Thus, to summarize: n_threads doesn't work in v2.1. What I'm doing now is using Spacy with joblib to read a dataset in minibatches.

Spacy released an example for that: [Spacy Multiprocessing](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2075#issuecomment-449074687), and it works perfectly.

I have a dataset with almost ~4M short text. Without using the example they released, it took almost 23 hours to finish parsing them, but using joblib with spacy, it took 1 hour and half to finish!

To reference the readers of this question to Spacy Multiprocessing example: [Spacy Multiprocessing](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2075#issuecomment-449074687)

Comment: The link you've posted does not contain any example. I guess it'd be better if you've post in right in here, with a reference to that link.